# Get the real path of a file

Tags: 8, files

I am creating an Excel reading module in Drupal 8. I want to get the real path of a file for reading it from a path like public://2016-03/Places.xls.

What function should I call for getting the real path of a file?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/8

Comment: For reading with what? That path works with almost everything, e.g. file_get_contents('public://...') works just fine.

Comment: I got the answer in terms of drupal 8 it is ` \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('public://2016-03/Places_2.xlsx')`

Comment: Post it as a response and accept it as solution. That will help others with the same question.

Comment: I had a similar situation, but ended up going with [file_create_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/8.5.x) because it can handle `managed files (These are files that have either been uploaded by users or were generated automatically (for example through CSS aggregation))` and `shipped files (those outside of the files directory, which ship as part of Drupal core or contributed modules or themes)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by digging Drupal code.
We can get the real path or absolute path by using the *file_system* service.

```
$absolute_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('public://2016-03/Places_2.xlsx');
```

Comment: are these for files upload through Drupal? What happens if they are hosted externally?

`The use of this method is discouraged, because it does not work for remote URIs. Except in rare cases, URIs should not be manually resolved.` is mentioned the documention for [FileSystem::realpath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Arealpath/8.5.x)

Answer (score 19):

@Nisam answer was right but now it's deprecated: [function drupal_realpath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/8.2.x)

> Deprecated
>
> in Drupal 8.0.x-dev, will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0. Use
> \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem::realpath().

So you should use [FileSystem::realpath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Arealpath/8.2.x). In Drupal 9 is the way to go because `drupal_realpath` has been removed.

Example:

```
$file = File::load($file_id);
$uri = $file->getFileUri();
$stream_wrapper_manager = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaUri($uri);
$file_path = $stream_wrapper_manager->realpath();
```

Comment: That was my first thought too.. 
I'm still missing something because when it gets to Twig, the path gets twisted into /files/...

   $module_handler = \Drupal::moduleHandler();
    $module_path = $module_handler->getModule('company_partners_sync')->getPath();

    $premier_tech_image = $module_path . '/images/premier-technology.png';
    $variables['default_partner_logo'] = $premier_tech_image;